# average and confidence interval with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, confidence-interval

I have a raw data like this:

```
x1      val1
x1      val2
x1      val3
x1      val4
x2      val5
x2      val6
x2      val7
x3      val8
...
```

And I want to make a line plot with x1,x2,...xn  as X value and average(val1,val2,val3,val4), average(val5,val6... as Y values.

- Is it possible in gnuplot?
- Can I display confidence-interval?
- Can I ignore the highest and lowest value in each x?

Thank you!!

PD: [This is an example did with PROC GPLOT](http://www.wuss.org/proceedings09/09WUSSProceedings/papers/anl/ANL-Rutledge.pdf)

Comment: This is a very tricky problem to do using only gnuplot.  If you can write a little script which will format the data properly for you in a different language, the task would be much more simple.  `plot "< myscript mydatafile" using ...`

Comment: Thank you, I use awk for format the data.

Answer (score 0):

In general gnuplot can't do averaging very well. However, in your case you might be lucky, if your data is sorted by X-values and you want to average over lines with the same X-value,  you can tell gnuplot to average/sum using the "smooth" option. See "help smooth unique" and "help smooth frequency".  So you should be able to do something like

plot 'raw_data.txt' u 1:2 smooth unique

I don't know how to skip points in gnuplot without a lot of effort. To make more complicated calculation you can always write your own data-processing function and then run that over the data and plot it afterwards, see for example:

http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/01/further-new-features-in-gnuplot-44.html

or

http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/search?q=average

But those things are probably best handled by an external script.